# Efficient way to compute the integral $\int_0^{\infty}d\tau f(\tau)\int_0^{\tau}d\theta g(\tau-\theta)h(\theta)$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-complexity, convolution

I would like to know if there exists a way in which the double integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}d\tau f(\tau)\int_0^{\tau}d\theta g(\tau-\theta)h(\theta)$$

can be computed (numerically) efficiently. It is similar to the integral of the convolution between $g$ and $h$ weighted by the function $f$, and I was wondering if I could exploit a result akin to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration).

Some additional details:

In reality the function $h(t)$ is $h(x,t)$, and it's a p.d.f over $x$ for every value of $t$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, h(x,t) = 1 \quad \forall t$$

Also the functions $f$ and $g$ are p.d.f.s so they satisfy

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt\, f(t) = \int_0^{\infty} dt\, g(t) = 1$$

The domain of $f(t)$, $g(t)$ and $h(\cdot,t)$ is $t \in [0,\infty)$

Comment: It is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) j(t)dt = j \ast f_-(0)$ where $j = g 1_{> 0} \ast h 1_{> 0}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your notation. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @reuns I forgot to tag you